# Treat array values as hex not ascii

Tags: php, arrays, hex, byte

I have a string of hex bytes, like so:

> 4E44B4096780031713077AB80040052F2F0C1335000000046D372B27230F150E04000000FFFFFF020000FFFFFFFFFF

I split these into bytes by using

> $arr1 = str_split($str, 2);

That gives me a nice array of the bytes. However, PHP seems to treat the array elements as ascii, not hex. That makes it impossible for me to make bitmasks etc on them.

How can I declare these bytes as hex?

Comment: can you show us how your array looks like

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 4E
    [1] => 44
    [2] => B4
    [3] => 09
    [4] => 67
    [5] => 80
    [6] => 03
    [7] => 17
    [8] => 13
    [9] => 07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hexadecimal and even more ASCII are not types of variable and this, in any language.

[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is only a character table, not a string.
Hexadecimal is a way to represent a number in base 16, but this representation itself is no longer a number but a character string.

Converting an hexadecimal string to decimal can be done with the function [`hexdec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php). Since you have an array of hexadecimal strings, you can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to transform each item.

```
$result = array_map('hexdec', str_split($str, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tested this out and it seems to work. However, I have the added challenge of having to a) flip the sequence of 2 (or more) bytes, b) combine them, c) make bitmasking on them. I can't figure out how to do a & b - whenever I do the result turns out wrong. Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: @Mikkel: Since "vampirising" a question is highly discouraged on SO, I suggest to post a new question for this task (take the time to well explain what you are trying to do and show examples of input and desired output for one or several items). However, feel free to post the link to this new question in comments.

Comment: Right you are - and here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837696/flipping-and-combining-hex-based-array-values